# AngularJS HTML audio player

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html5-audio, angularjs-service

I'm creating a webpage using AngularJS. I am trying to play an audio file that is loaded when the page has finished loading. 
This is the html code I'm using:

```
<audio controls="controls">
     <source ng-src="{{audioFile}}" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

And this is my AngularJS file where the audio player doesn't play anything.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Quiz',
        function ($scope, $routeParams, Quiz) {            
            $scope.quiz = Quiz.get({quizId: $routeParams.quizId}, function() {
                $scope.audioFile = "Link to some audioFile";
            });
        }
    ]);
```

But it works in the below code when I skip the service:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Quiz',
        function ($scope, $routeParams, Quiz) {            
             $scope.audioFile = "Link to some audioFile";
        }
    ]);
```

Is there any way to make this work when waiting for the response from the service?

Comment: You have several problems in this code which would block running. I believe its written by hand and not the code from your project. Missing comma after DI, additional apostrophe in function params, missing bracket after Quiz.get.

Please provide exact code. And also check what you have in console.

Comment: Is your GET actually returning the correct data?

Comment: Yes, I have tried logging it many times and it gives the correct data. If I copy that data and assign $scope.audioFile to that value outside my GET it works. 
If I copy the data and assign $scope.audioFile to that data inside the Quiz.get function this doesn't work either.
I just think that my html doesn't reload or something when the correct data is assigned to $scope.audioFile in the GET function

Answer (score 0):

[This is a simple directive](https://github.com/bahday/AngularJSHTMLPlayer) audio player on AngularJS. Easy to insert and use, hopefully help you.

```
<player-directive ng-controller="YourCtrl" playlist="{{Your.tracks}}"></player-directive>
```